# Setting the title of a Motif Window

Tags: c, x11, motif

I am trying to set the title of a toplevel Motif 2.1 window.

From O'Reilly Volume Six A, I have seen that in Motif 2.1 `XtVaOpenApplication` is recommended to create a toplevel Widget.

In [this appendix](http://www.ist.co.uk/motif/books/vol6A/AppendixA.fm.html#450348) it can be seen how `options` and `XtNumber(options)` are used to act on resources via argument list.

I have tried to use it to generate an optional flag `-title WINDOW_TITLE` while invoking the program, without sucess.

This is what I have tried:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 
#include <Xm/Xm.h>
#include <Xm/PushB.h>
 
static XrmOptionDescRec options[] = {
    { "-title", "XmNtitle", XrmoptionIsArg, NULL },
};
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    Widget          toplevel;             /* Top Level Button */
    XtAppContext    app;                  /* Application Context */
    char            *window_title = NULL; /* Top Level Window Title */
    
    /* INITIALIZE TOP LEVEL WINDOW */
    XtSetLanguageProc(NULL, NULL, NULL);
    toplevel = XtVaOpenApplication( &app, argv[0], options, XtNumber(options), &argc, argv, NULL, sessionShellWidgetClass, NULL);
    
    /* REALIZE TOPLEVEL WINDOW AND LAUNCH APPLICATION LOOP */
    XtRealizeWidget(toplevel);
    XtAppMainLoop(app);
    
    return 0;

}
```

The program compiles but it does not react to `-title MYTITLE` command line argument.

This is the `makefile` (works on FreeBSD 12):

```
test:           test.o
                cc -L/usr/local/lib -O -o test test.o -lXm -lXt -lX11

test.o:         test.c
                cc -I/usr/local/include -c test.c
```

How can I change the title of the window based on an optional argument named `-title`?

Comment: I don't know, but I think this *parses* the command line only. To set the title, you must also act on the parsed values.

Comment: AFAIK `-title` is one of the standard x toolkit command line options and is processed automatically by `XtVaOpenApplication`. You should not need to specify it in `XrmOptionDescRec`.

Comment: That's correct and I was not aware of it.

Answer (score 4):

The correct xrm option line is

```
{"-title", ".title", XrmoptionSepArg, NULL}
```

You don't actually need to specify it because it is in the default Xt option table.

In general you omit `XmN` when specifying xrm resource names.

Comment: I did not know that `-title` was part of the default Xt option table. It is not needed as you said. However, I also tried with `{"-foo", "title", XrmoptionSepArg, NULL}` so you can change the title -as a mere example as it is now clear that it is not needed- with `-foo MYTITLE`.  I have tried removing the dot before the `title` and it works too. So instead of `{"-foo", ".title", XrmoptionSepArg, NULL}` it can be `{"-foo", "title", XrmoptionSepArg, NULL}`. Is there any reason for using the dot?

Comment: I'm not sure about the leading dot, looks like it is redundant but it is being used in the X11 sources.

Comment: A different but related question about `XrmOptionDescRec` struct array can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68336568/can-you-use-struct-xrmoptiondescrec-array-to-pass-non-motif-related-parameters-t  Can I use the array of structs to pass non-X11 related parameters? If not, how can I incorporate them into the program?

Answer (score 1):

In my Motif programs, I use Xlib directly, since Motif does not seem to handle correctly the UTF8 setting of window titles using XmNtitle property. Most modern window managers expect UTF8 string passed as _NET_MW_NAME.

```
void setWindowTitleUTF8(Widget w, char *title)
{
 static Atom atoms[3];
 static bool first = TRUE;
 if (first)
  {
   static char *atom_names[] = {"_NET_WM_NAME", "_NET_WM_ICON", "UTF8_STRING"};
   first = FALSE;
   XInternAtoms(XtDisplay(w), atom_names, 3, FALSE, atoms);
  }
 XChangeProperty(XtDisplay(w), XtWindow(w), atoms[_NET_WM_NAME], atoms[UTF8_STRING], 8,
  PropModeReplace, (unsigned char *) title, strlen(title));
}
```

Make sure you call it on XtParent() of your widget, so it is applied to top level widget shell.

Answer (score 0):

Please investigate further yourself (I'm no X/Motif expert), but sth seems to be off with the argument parsing.
Replacing options with NULL ant its size with 0 in call `XtVaOpenApplication` call seems to do the trick:
`toplevel = XtVaOpenApplication( &app, argv[0], NULL, 0, &argc, argv, NULL, sessionShellWidgetClass, NULL);`