# Can you use struct XrmOptionDescRec array to pass non-Motif related parameters to an application?

Tags: c, x11, xlib, motif

I have seen how to configure xrm resource names via XrmOptionDescRec struct array. An example of this can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68325648/setting-the-title-of-a-motif-window/) question.

I am wondering if I can also pass non-X11 related arguments via this way.

In particular, if I want to pass the name of a named pipe to the application so the X11 application opens that particular named pipe,

1. would it be using XrmOptionDescRec struct array an option?
2. Can I set up and retrieve arbitrary resource names?
3. If so, how do I retrieve the argument value?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 
#include <Xm/Xm.h>
#include <Xm/PushB.h>
 
static XrmOptionDescRec options[] = {
    { "-namedpipe", "namedpipe", XrmoptionSepArg, NULL },
};
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    Widget          toplevel;             /* Top Level Button */
    XtAppContext    app;                  /* Application Context */
    char            *window_title = NULL; /* Top Level Window Title */
    
    /* INITIALIZE TOP LEVEL WINDOW */
    XtSetLanguageProc(NULL, NULL, NULL);
    toplevel = XtVaOpenApplication( &app, argv[0], options, XtNumber(options), &argc, argv, NULL, sessionShellWidgetClass, NULL);

    /* HOW WOULD I GET HERE named_pipe ASSIGNED ????? */
    char named_pipe[256];
    ...
    
    /* REALIZE TOPLEVEL WINDOW AND LAUNCH APPLICATION LOOP */
    XtRealizeWidget(toplevel);
    XtAppMainLoop(app);
    
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You can set and get any resource by name. XrmGetResource. For a code example see e.g. [this](https://gist.github.com/dcat/05dc5d45e8c60f2645da). If you do it this way, you can set the resource in any way X11 lets you, and not just from the command line.

Comment: This helps, I am going through the code example you have provided and through Chapter 11 of O'Reilly Volume One Xlib Programming Manual to further understand how this works.

Comment: By using `XtVaOpenApplication` you get command line resources parsed and merged into the Resources Database. Not only that but it seems that it handles the different resource files that the system might have (how many and in which particular order, I do not know). https://linux.die.net/man/3/xtvaopenapplication If that is the case, what can I use as `XrmDatabase database` while invoking `XrmGetResource`? The example you point builds the databases using Xlib resource manager functions, not `XtVaOpenApplication`

Comment: I.E., where `XtVaOpenApplication` would go in the pointed code example? Before `XrmInitialize`? Shall something else be added or removed due to the fact of using `XtVaOpenApplication`?

Comment: If I have understood it correctly, and from Chapter 4 of (Volume Four, X Toolkit Intrinsics Programming Manual), there is an example named `xbitmap4` which defines a struct (`AppData appdata`) with all the application resources to get. Then a `static Xresrouce resources[] = {` is defined which precisely defines each application resource. After that you get and iterate over the application resources via `XtGetApplicationResources`. That would be AFAIK the Motif/Xt way and not using `XrmGetResource` which uses the base Xlib functionality (which is encapsulated the minute you use Xt/Motif).

Comment: My expertise ends about here :)

Comment: Your expertise helped to locate this Xlib / Xt difference of handling the resource database. Using Xlib to directly manage the resources seems cumbersome as you need to cover semi manually all potential resource sources. That seems to have been addressed by Xt.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone interested. In Xt/Motif applications this seems to be the way to handle application command line parameters as resources (they have the advantage of being handled smoothly by the Xt wrappers around Xlib resource manager functions). So basically you will be able to define the argument in user, application and system-wide resource files, and also via command line.

```
#define XtNnamedPipe "namedPipe"
#define XtCNamedPipe "NamedPipe"

typedef struct {
    String named_pipe;
} AppData;

AppData app_data;

static XtResource resources[] = {
    {
        XtNnamedPipe,
        XtCNamedPipe,
        XtRString,
        sizeof(String),
        XtOffsetOf(AppData, named_pipe),
        XtRString,
        NULL
    },
};

static XrmOptionDescRec options[] = {
    {"-namedpipe",  "namedPipe",    XrmoptionSepArg,    "/tmp/namedpipe0"},
};

...


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    ...

    toplevel = XtVaOpenApplication( 
        &app, argv[0], options, XtNumber(options), &argc, argv, NULL, sessionShellWidgetClass,
        XmNwidth, 400, XmNheight, 300, NULL
    );

    ...

    /* GET APPLICATION RESOURCES */
    XtGetApplicationResources(
        toplevel,
        &app_data,
        resources,
        XtNumber(resources),
        NULL,
        0);

    printf("DEBUG: %s\n", app_data.named_pipe);       

    ...
}
```